# Compactness of a group with a bounded left-invariant metric

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, metric-spaces, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a group equipped with a left-invariant metric $d$: that is, $(G,d)$ is a metric space and $d(xy,xz) = d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in G$.  Suppose further that $(G,d)$ is connected, locally compact, and bounded.  Must $(G,d)$ be compact?

I can show from the local compactness that $(G,d)$ is complete.  I don't see how to get it to be totally bounded, but I also can't think of a counterexample.

If it helps, you can assume that $(G,d)$ is a topological group (i.e. right translation and inversion are homeomorphisms; we already know that left translation is an isometry).  I would even be interested in the case where $G$ is a finite-dimensional Lie group and $d$ induces the manifold topology, but I do not want to assume that $d$ is induced by a left-invariant Riemannian metric.

Comment: This question is interesting. By the way, do you know if existence of a bounded left invariant Riemannian metric implies compactness of the Lie group?

Comment: @AsafShachar: I believe that follows from the metric completeness thanks to the Hopf-Rinow theorem.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $\mathbb R$ with the bounded left invariant metric
$$d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$$

Comment: Why is this left invariant? Maybe it's obvious but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @ThomasE. $|(x+a)-(y+a)|=|x-y|$.

Comment: right! Because it's an additive group. Thanks.